# Php working with time interval and cronjob

Tags: php, cron

my client has a restaurant with an online delivery. We are adding the option to the users to schedule their order. The restaurant delivery opens at 11am and closes at 15pm. The user can schedule their order in 30 minutes intervals, something like: 12:00, 12:30, 1:00, 1:30, etc...

I thought in building a script to run every minute and check if it's time to delivery the order. The problem is that my hosting provider only allows the cronjobs to run every 10 minutes. Another problem that I found is that sometimes it "loses" the count so instead of running every 10 minutes, it runs every 11 minutes, or 12 minutes...which is making my job hard.

I just want some ideas in how to achieve what I need. I'm not asking you to code, but maybe tell me what would be a good solution or approach to not lose any scheduled delivery time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your current cron pattern?

Comment: It sounds like you're using shared hosting, and it sounds like you're on an overloaded server. You know you can get cloud instances for like $5/mo, if not lower, right? Then you have full control of everything and can do whatever you like.

Comment: @Sammitch I know that. The problem is that my client has everything setup on this server and doesn't want to move away! :(

Comment: Yes, but your client also wants something that the current host is unwilling and/or incapable of providing. You don't have to turn everything off and migrate immediately; spin up an instance, test, plan, test, test, plan to test, test the plan, plan the test, schedule a move, and then do the thing. :P